# Why don't we use did in this case?

Tags: questions

Can someone explain the use of "did" when used with a question. Why do we say 'Who invented the bicyle' and not 'who did invent the bicycle?' I know it is incorrect with "did" - but why?

Comment: It's not incorrect—and you can say it. *"No, she's not the person who invented the bicycle." "Really? Well then, who **did** invent the bicycle?"* It's just not normally said without that kind of context or emphasis.

Comment: In open interrogatives, supportive _do_ is used just to carry the stress that marks emphatic polarity.